# Having a custom Html.DropDownListFor in MVC, with few entities disabled/ enabled?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, html.dropdownlistfor

I have used a dropdownlist with static values before and was able to manually disable some item in the list (As i wanted headers for each set of items). I am looking to do the same dynamically once i get the list from the database.

- Looking forward on including a header functionality for the list from the database.
- The headers and the list would be obtained from the database.

Below is the static code that i used to include this feature.

```html
<select class="combobox form-control" id="sel" name="iArea">
  <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none">Select an option</option>
  <option value="" disabled>Health</option>  <!-- Disabled Header -->
  <option value="WP">&nbsp&nbsp Creating a world wide network, bringing people together by not having any distinction by race, caste or religion?</option>
  <option value="FL">&nbsp&nbsp Tracking down loved one's in a crowded or emergency situation at a cost effective manner?</option>
  <!-- Enabled List for a header above -->
  <option value="Others">&nbsp&nbsp Others</option>
  <option value="OfBT" disabled>Social Service</option>  <!-- Disabled Header -->
  <option value="Others">&nbsp&nbsp Helping the old folks get a place to stay?</option>
</select>
```

I wanted the same done dynamically, i am using @Html.DropDownListFor in the view page of my action in MVC architecture.

The table structure that i am using is as below. The summaries belong to a set, the header that i was looking at would be the set name. And the list of entities that falls under this set name would come under that header. The set name/ header would remain disabled, only for illustration. The entities corresponding to that set name can be selected/enabled in the dropdown list. I am using MVC 4 architecture.

[Image of Database Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoXXt.jpg)

[Drop Down List screenshot for the table structure described above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8CcD.jpg)

Comment: You use the [<optgroup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) element for generating 'headers'

Comment: But how can it be done dynamically? Where the list is populated from the database. I am using MVC architecture currently and a @Html.DropDownListFor as the drop down element command.

Comment: You have not even shown you database structure/models (we are not psychic). And are you using MVC5, which has overloads to do this out of the box.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I might have missed that out somehow, sorry about that. I have attached a screenshot of the table, that i am taking the data from and the drop down list UI image. Hoping this is what you were looking for.

Comment: And what version of MVC are you using (MVC5 has a overload of `DropDownListFor()` that does grouping, otherwise you will need to create your own HtmlExtension method, or generate the html manually inside a loop.

Comment: I am using MVC 4, guess overload isn't there in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@StephenMuecke, I ended up creating my HTML code in the MVC view, by looping. But wouldn't have been possible without you guys guiding, me being a beginner and all. I have explained the concept here; the List section would be obtained from the database. This worked perfectly, though i guess it may hit the performance, if the data for the drop down is a lot.

**The Action Section in the controller**

```
UserData.InnovateSection = new List<DropDownList>{new DropDownList { label = "Health", value = "Creating a world wide network, bringing people together by not having any distinction by race, caste or religion?" },
                        new DropDownList { label = "Health", value = "Tracking down loved one's in a crowded or emergency situation at a cost effective manner?" },
                        new DropDownList { label = "Social Service", value = "Others" }};
                var headers = (from it in UserData.InnovateSection
                               select it.label).Distinct().ToList();
                var headersLength = headers.Count;
                int i = 0, k;
                UserData.Innovate = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                while (i < headersLength)
                {
                    k = 0;
                    foreach (var item in UserData.InnovateSection)
                    {
                        if (headers[i] == item.label && k == 0)
                        {
                            UserData.Innovate.Append("<optgroup label = " + "\"" + item.label + "\"" + ">");
                            k = 1;
                        }
                        if (headers[i] == item.label)
                        {
                            UserData.Innovate.Append("<option value= " + "\"" + item.value + "\"" + ">" + item.value + "</option>");
                        }

                    }

                    UserData.Innovate.Append("</optgroup>");
                    i++;
                }
                return View(UserData);
```

**The HTML code in the view being rendered**

```html
<select class="combobox form-control" id="sel" name="IdeaArea">
  <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none">Select an option</option>
     @Html.Raw(@Model.Innovate) <!-- Model created goes inside the Raw tag to convert string to HTML DOM -->
</select>
```

And i got the custom dropdown that i was seeking, in the end. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<GroupedSelectListItem> item;
item = new List<GroupedSelectListItem> { 
    new GroupedSelectListItem() { Value="volvo", Text="Volvo", GroupName="Swedish Cars", GroupKey="1", Disabled=true },
    new GroupedSelectListItem() { Value="saab", Text="Saab",GroupName="Swedish Cars", GroupKey="1" }, 
    new GroupedSelectListItem() { Value="mercedes", Text="Mercedes", GroupName="German Cars", GroupKey="2" },
    new GroupedSelectListItem() { Value="audi", Text="Audi", GroupName="German Cars", GroupKey="2",Selected=true }};
```

And then:

```
@Html.DropDownGroupList("Cars", item, "-- Select Car --", 
            new Dictionary<string, object>() { 
                { "data-val", "true" }, 
                { "data-val-required", "The Car field is required." } 
            })
```

To get something like this:

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-required="The Car field is required." id="Cars" name="Cars" class="valid">
        <option value="">-- Select Car --</option>
        <optgroup label="Swedish Cars" value="1" disabled="">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="German Cars" value="2">
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="audi">Audi</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
```

Comment: Blake, Thanks for your response. But I was not able to add DropDownGroupList in the MVC view. I used DropDownListFor instead. But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IdeaArea, Model.IdeaAreaCompact.Select( x=> new SelectListItem() { 
                                                                                                                                { "data-val", "true" }, 
                                                                                                                                { "data-val-required", "The Car field is required." } 
                                                                                                                            }), "-- Select --")